# Octave specgram: How do I plot negative frequencies

Tags: spectrogram, octave

I have a complex signal and I'm trying to use Octave to plot a spectrogram. I found the specgram function, and it's close to what I want, but I can't figure out how to get it to display negative frequencies. Can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

The `specgram` function from the `signal` package does not handle complex input fully and discards the negative frequency information.

However, there is a function called `sgram` in the `ltfat` package that does handle complex input properly and produces the expected -Fs/2 to Fs/2 spectrogram.

https://gnu-octave.github.io/packages/ltfat/

[image: sgram output with default options]

Today I saw a few errors installing the ltfat package on octave 8.4.0, but sgram still worked when all was said and done.